# Передать параметр в ViewModel из Behavior WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Каким образом из реализации поведения контрола можно передать свойство или параметр во `ViewModel`. 
В окне имеется `PasswordBox` у которого реализовано поведение окна обработку `Password` с помощью `Behavior`.

Код `Behavior`

```
 public class PasswordBehavior:Behavior<PasswordBox>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Password", typeof(string), typeof(PasswordBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        private bool _skipUpdate;

        public string Password
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PasswordProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += PasswordBox_PasswordChanged;

        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged -= PasswordBox_PasswordChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

            if (e.Property == PasswordProperty)
            {
                if (!_skipUpdate)
                {
                    _skipUpdate = true;
                    AssociatedObject.Password = e.NewValue as string;
                    _skipUpdate = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _skipUpdate = true;
            Password = AssociatedObject.Password;
            _skipUpdate = false;
        }

    }
```

Реализация XAML

```
<PasswordBox
            Name="Password"
            MaxLength="6">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:PasswordBehavior Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </PasswordBox>
```

В идеале потом переделаю под `SecureString` или попробую передать хэш

Comment: А что не так с вашей имплементацией? (Только не говорите «не работает», это не описывает проблему.)

Comment: @VladD не могу понять как привязать к свойству `ViewModel` свойство из `Behavior` по принципу MVVM. Получается что я передал параметр в `DataContext=ViewModel`

Comment: Ну так `Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"` — это ж и есть привязка к VM, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD я думал что 'PasswordBehavior:Behavior<PasswordBox>' не будет являться частью ViewModel так как содержит в себе UI элементы.

Comment: Не, PasswordBehaviour — это View, а не VM. А Password, который из `{Binding Password ...}` — это как раз свойство из VM.

Comment: @VladD значит это я оплошал, я думал то биндится свойство из `PasswordBehavior`, просто оно там так же называется

Comment: Ну так всё правильно же. Свойство `Password` из `PasswordBehavior` (`Password=`) биндится к свойству `Password` из VM (`{Binding Password ...}`).

Comment: @VladD точно, прошу прощения еще не полностью разобрался с `Behavior` спасибо большое за разъяснение:)